# How to specify sqlite db file path in react-native-sqlite-storage for Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

I'm using `react-native-sqlite-storage` plugin to build my Android app.

I want to save sqlite db file to **/storage/emulator/0/Documents**, I wonder how can I implement this by `SQLite.openDatabase`

I've tried following code but it doesn't work

```
const db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: database_name,  createFromLocation : "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/"}, openInfo, errorInfo);
```

Comment: If it does not work then what happens instead? Errors? Exceptions?